# how to convert string to array ? as i am getting an array but it is in string format

Tags: php

i have a `var` `$subject` when i `print` it by `echo $subject` i get this `[["2","subject2","0","0"],["4","ccd","50","5"]]`

but when i do `echo gettype($subject)` i get `string`

because of this i am not able to use `foreach` `loop` in order to iterate over `$subject`

how can i get it in array `[["2","subject2","0","0"],["4","ccd","50","5"]]` format

Comment: This looks like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert that string into an array:

```
$subject = '[["2","subject2","0","0"],["4","ccd","50","5"]]';
print_r(json_decode($subject, true));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => subject2 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => ccd [2] => 50 [3] => 5 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1elH2)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @nick use the json_decode function to make it an array.

```
$subject = '[["2","subject2","0","0"],["4","ccd","50","5"]]';
$stringToArray = json_decode($subject, true);
foreach($stringToArray as $key => $value){
    print_r($value);echo '<hr>';
}
```